# What are the roots of $ x^{2} = 2^{x} $?

Tags: calculus, roots

What are the roots of $ x^{2} = 2^{x} $? I drew the graphs and found $ x = 2 $ and $ x = 4 $, and there is one other root in $ [-1,0] $. Can anyone describe an algebraic method to obtain all roots?

Comment: This question was already asked here. There is no nice formula to get the solution. You either need numerical methods or the Lambert-W-Function.

Comment: The negative solution is $-0.7666646959621230931112044225$

Answer (score 2):

Taking the logarithm and assuming $x>0$,

$$2\ln(x)=x\ln(2),$$ or $$\frac{\ln(x)}x=\frac{\ln(2)}2.$$

The derivative of the LHS is $$\frac{1-\ln(x)}{x^2},$$ which has a single root at $x=e$.

As there is a single extremum and the function is continuous, the equation

$$\frac{\ln(x)}x$$has at most two roots, which you found.

---

For negative $x$, the equation turns to

$$\frac{\ln(-x)}x=\frac{\ln(2)}2.$$

As the LHS function is positive only on one side of the extremum, there is at most one negative root. This root exists as the function goes to $\infty$, but it has no closed form.

Comment: With this method, we do not get the negative solution.

Comment: It has at most two *positive* solutions. But if $x<0$ then $\ln(x^2)$ is defined and $\ln(x)$ is not, so $\ln(x^2)=2 \ln(x)$ fails there.

Comment: That's right, should be $2\ln(|x|)$.